# HTML code for button click limitation

Tags: html

This is my code, and it's for SMS spoofing service. I need a system, which will control how many SMS messages can user send. For example every user has 5 messages to send, and all above 5 is forbiden.
I need you to help me to make a simple HTML code, which will show me the message like "It's enough" when they click submit button more then 5 times.

```
  <tr>
   <td>Password:</td>
   <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="toro"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>To: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="to" size="30" placeholder="+38164,+38162 etc..." /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>From: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="from" size="30" placeholder="Facebook, 911 etc... " /></td>
  <tr>
    <td>Message: </td>
    <td><textarea name="message"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
  <tr>
```

Comment: You can't do that with HTML

Comment: You could with javascript, but that would not be very safe. You need to do it server side with some kind of database where you store users and their sent sms.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with HTML. Can be done with jquery or javascript as below. But my suggestion would be to have a counter in server side. Because, if the page is refreshed, the counter would be reset and again SMS would be able to be sent for another 5 more times and the cycle continues.. This is not proper restriction to have only client side check.

```
<script>
   var clickcount = 0;
   var maxlimit = 5;
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        if (clickcount >=maxlimit)
    {
        alert ("Sorry, You have used your max limit of "+maxlimit+" sms for the day ");
    }
        else if ($("#formID").valid())
    {
        clickcount++;
        $("#formID").submit();

    }
    }); 
});

</script>
```